# Symfony2: Is there a symfony2 plugin for Aptana/Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, symfony, plugins, aptana

Is there a Plugin for Eclipse/Aptana that provides autocompletion and other helpers for Symfony2 projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best plugin out there is probably the [Symfony2 Eclipse Plugin](http://symfony.dubture.com/).

It provides:

- autocompletion:

  - services
  - route-names
  - template-names
  - translation-keys,
  - container-parameters
  - ...
- config validation
- annotation support
- ...

Comment: thank you, I always enjoyed coding with eclipse.
this plugin is a real help.

Comment: this plugin needs as minimum requirements:
    Java 6 and
    Eclipse **4.2 (Juno)**

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea for Aptana & Eclipse, but [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) comes with plugins for Symfony 2 (and 1) in the PHP and/or complete version. You have autocomplete and syntax coloration for PHP, Twig template, Yaml, xliff, etc...

Notice : some limitations with code completion when you use services for example.

Comment: Guess that's a little out of the scope of his question. Many IDEs and Editors (i.e. PHPStorm) provide decent integration out of the box or have symfony2-plugins available :) Haven't looked into Netbeans but the Eclipse plugin i mentioned in my answer is exceptionally good. It definitely beats PHPStorm's default symfony2 features (i.e. lacking annotation support). Anyways +1 from me :)

Comment: Yep sorry, but I thought that this information should help anyway. I used to develop with Eclipse for Java projects. May be I should give a try for PHP projects too. Sorry again if I was out of the scope of this question... +1 for you too ;)